# Interrupting a Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization

We're using the gauge Google Chart applet to visually monitor some message transfer failure rates on a SOAP interface we have via AJAX.

My desire is to have the background of the page flash red and white when the fail rate is at 50% or higher, and just have a plain white background when not. We're monitoring two SOAP interfaces with two separate gauges, so they can't step on each other when turning the flashing on or off. To that end, I can get it to turn on but not turn off, and every 5 seconds (the interval of the AJAX refresh) that the dial is over 50, it will re-call the flashing loop which will eventually run the flashing interval up so high that the page looks like a strobe light.

I'll admit this- I'm terrible at javascript.

Here's what I have so far:

For the flashing itself:

```
function changecolors(on) {
  x = 1;
  if (on === "on") {
    setInterval(change, 500);
  } else {
    x = 2;
    document.body.style.background = "white";
  }
}

function change() {
  if (x === 1) {
    color = "red";
    x = 2;
  } else {
    color = "white";
    x = 1;
  }
  document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

And the gauges:

```
function drawFAIL1() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Percent', 0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 320,
    redFrom: 50,
    redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom: 25,
    yellowTo: 50,
    minorTicks: 5,
    max: 100
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('fail1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fail1.php',
      success: function(response) {
        data.setValue(0, 1, response);
        chart.draw(data, options);
        setTimeout(getData, 5000);
        if (response > 49) {
          changecolors("on");
        } else {
          changecolors("off");
        }
      }
    });
  }
  getData();
}

function drawFAIL2() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Percent', 0]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 320,
    redFrom: 50,
    redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom: 25,
    yellowTo: 50,
    minorTicks: 5,
    max: 100
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('fail2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fail2.php',
      success: function(response) {
        data.setValue(0, 1, response);
        chart.draw(data, options);
        setTimeout(getData, 5000);
        if (response > 49) {
          changecolors("on");
        } else {
          changecolors("off");
        }
      }
    });
  }
  getData();
}
```

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different languages.

Comment: Apologies- did I say Java? I could have sworn that I kept it as javascript throughout.

Comment: Anyway you might wanted to ask how to stop an interval since this is your problem, but if you knew that you could have probably found it on google yourself.

Comment: Through much googling yesterday, I did know about clearInterval, but it seemed to be failing since the variable wasn't persisting each time the function was called. For example, fail 1 goes to 50, then 5 seconds later its at 52, it calls the function again; now intervalChangeColors is reassigned to the new interval. 5 seconds later the value drops to 45, so clearInterval is called, but only one of the intervalChangeColors is persistent, so the alert remains on.

Comment: oh sorry I did not notice this, When you have a variable which you assign setINterval to twice it will just contain the last reference the other one will be floating somewhere, so what you could do is like such.
clearInterval(variable);
variable = setInterval(func, 50);
This way you're sure you won't have duplicates.

Did you fix this already?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel an interval by clearing it, but you will need to keep a reference to the ID which you can do in a simple variable:
Example, see intervalChangeColors var being used in your changeColors function

```
var intervalChangeColors;
function changecolors(on) {
      x = 1;
      if (on === "on") {
        intervalChangeColors = setInterval(change, 500);
      } else {
        clearInterval(intervalChangeColors);
        x = 2;
        document.body.style.background = "white";
      }
    }
```

Referance:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

some simple code improvements:

change

```
if (response > 49) {
          changecolors("on");
        } else {
          changecolors("off");
        }
```

to:

```
changeColors(response > 49)
```

And

```
if (on === "on")
```

to

```
if (on)
```

Booleans are nice :)